# Pixellib, TensorFlow ускорение вычислений

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, selenium, tensorflow

Начал увлекаться анализом изображений на основе языка **python**.

Прочел несколько статей и выбрал подходящую для своего проекта библиотеку **pixellib**.

При написании скрипта задумался над **проблемой многопточности**.

***Немного о времени работы:***

1. Загрузка сайта и скачивание изображения - **12 секунд**.
2. Анализ **одного** изображения - **15 секунд**.
3. **Пункт 1** + Анализ **двух** изображений - **42 секунды**.

Соответственно при анализе ещё одного изображения время увеличивается на **15 секунд**.

Я принял решение сделать скрипт многопоточным, но время выполнения уменьшилось на **4-6 секунд (при 10 изображениях)**. Что довольно мало при больших объёмах изображений.

Исходный код скрипта:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import time
import urllib
import urllib.request
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

start_time = time.time()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang=en")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/alexp/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("url")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/").click()
time.sleep(1)
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div").text
time.sleep(1)
img_url = "body > div.challenge-container > div"
iframe01 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(img_url)
cssval = iframe01.value_of_css_property("background-image")
destination = "element1.png"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(cssval, destination)

segment_image = instance_segmentation(infer_speed = "fast" )
segment_image.load_model("C:\\Users\\alex\\work\\mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
if text == "1":
    target_class = segment_image.select_target_classes(person=True)
elif text == "2":
    target_class = segment_image.select_target_classes(car=True)

result = segment_image.segmentImage(
    image_path="element1.png",
    segment_target_classes=target_class,
)

objects_count = len(result[0]["scores"])
if objects_count > 0:
    urll = f"body > div.challenge-container > div[1]"
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(urll).click()

finish_time = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Время затраченное на работу: {finish_time}")
```

По итогу всех возможных манипуляций я так и не смог сократить время работы скрипта. Уже пробовал: **multiprocessing, threading**.

**Моя цель - уменьшение времени обработки изображений, например: обработка всех изображений (5-10 шт.) за время обработки (1-2 шт.)**

Буду рад каждому предложению или исправлению!

Comment: Замените селенимум, например requests

Comment: @СергейШашко дело не в скрипте по скачиванию изображения, время его выполнения меня устраивает, оно варьируется в диапазоне 11-13 секунд. А вот обработка занимает 15 - 150 секунд, т.к. каждое изображение анализируется отдельно.

Comment: В документации библиотеки написано, что одна картинка должна порядка секунды обрабатываться. Вы без `GPU` видимо код запускаете? Кардинально улучшить ситуацию можно только используя `GPU` для ускорения работы нейросети. А насчёт многопоточности - опять же, в какой среде вы скрипт запускаете? А то может у вас там полтора ядра `CPU` и параллелить исполнение просто некуда?

Comment: А ну да, куда я кликать буду. :) Ну тогда остается только multiprocessing. Eсли не секрет driver.get("url") куда ведет url?

Comment: @CrazyElf, верно, я пытался скачивать tensorflow и tensorfow-gpu, при запуске с gpu версией выходит сообщение об ошибке, что-то вроде: The `validate_indices` argument has no effect. Indices are always validated on CPU and never validated on GPU. Я пытался найти решение, но пару вариантов из гугла и видео не помогли. Пробовал с помощью conda воссоздавать идеальный образ для запуска, увы никак. Что касается системы - 2 ядра на 4 потока, слабовато, но думаю что при переводе на систему с более сильным процессором тайминги не уменьшатся.

Comment: @СергейШашко, сделал свой сайт для тестирования, ссылочку предоставить не могу)